# RxJava 2 - Observable.zip() never emits

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

I'm new with Reactive.
I want to collect data from different sources and process the result.
To do that I'm using the *Observable.zip()* method. But it never emits so the callback is never called.
What have I done wrong?

Here is an example of the code I try to implement:

```
public void loadData() {

    Observable.zip(
            Observable.just(42),
            Observable.just(43),
            Observable.just(44),
            (integer, integer2, integer3) ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "zip method called") // This is never called
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the Observable to make it do it's job.

For example you might do this:

```
public void loadData() {
    Observable.zip(
            Observable.just(42),
            Observable.just(43),
            Observable.just(44),
            (integer, integer2, integer3) ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "zip method called")
    )
    .subscribe(); //you can also send 3 parameters optional parameters, onNext action, onError action and onComplete action.
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah of course! Idiot that I am. Many thanks you saved my day! :)